# GIT Says "No space left on device" But The Drive Has More Than Enough

Tags: git, centos, centos7

So I am trying to add an entire project to a new repo on CentOS using "git add -A" and after a while I get the error message. The thing is, the drive this project is on has 1TB of FREE space so it's talking rubbish. I am unable to add the project to GIT because of this.

I know this has been asked a lot, but I have found no solid answer as to why it's saying I have no disc space when there is more than enough. The project itself is only 500MB!

Comment: Check permissions for the git user.

Comment: all the files are chown' to the user I am logged in with on ssh.

Comment: Trust the error message ;)

Comment: can't trust a liar lol

Comment: What happens if you add a single file or a subdir. If this also fails it is pretty likely that you have a problem with your permissions.

Comment: If your disk has 1TB you may have different partitions. How big is the partitions you are currently working on? `df -h` is your friend

Comment: no partitions, the work files run in a CentOS VM with dynamic drive which is hosted on a 1tb drive while the host os is on a separate ssd. There is some kind of problem that may be permissions, I'm not able to write a new file at all. I'll clear the entire project and start again, maybe have done something down the line.

Comment: could it be you ran out of inodes? check with "df -i"

Comment: Also check for quotas: see https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-disk-quotas-managing.html

Comment: Trying to use quotaoff off says command not found, I assume this means no quotas are on? @max630 I'm not sure what an inode is, but running the command df -I shows that it's very likely I did run out of them!

Comment: In the case of the inodes , from reading you can't increase them, so how am I supposed to add this large project to the git repo then?